# Laravel 4.0 - Anything beyond root "not found"

Tags: apache, laravel-4, apache2

I have an application running just fine locally via Ubuntu 12.04 (Vagrant).

However, when I attempt to access *some* routes from my production server (Also Ubuntu 12.04) I get an error:

```
//sample error
InvalidArgumentException 
View [orders.create] not found.
```

I've done everything with composer and artisan that needs to be done, so I'm assuming this is an Apache/.htaccess error. I have mod_rewrite enabled, and anything that is a dynamic route (controller, resource, etc.) is not working, although explicit routes do.

Is there something I can check for in my apache configs? I've tried to mirror everything as best I can with my local environment and my production server.

Comment: Have you tried using PHP in-built serve? Try running `$ php artisan serve` on your CLI, then access `http://localhost:8000`

Comment: can you confirm that your view orders.create exist: `app/views/orders/create[.blade].php`?

Comment: @CreativityKills - As I mentioned, the app runs on a 12.04 LTS/Apache environment, what benefit would I get from doing this? I know the application runs.

Comment: @zwacky - Thanks for the response! The application is running locally, so I can indeed confirm the view exists. I can cat the view from the directory.

Comment: @jakeharris `artisan serve` will take care of the server configuration like setting doc root to /public. ideally you don't need to fiddle with server confs or htdocs at all.

Comment: @zwacky This is a production server. I can't serve the application with `artisan serve`, heh.

Comment: Do you have the proper permissions set to the specific views folder? When copying to remote through FTP the client tends to change permissions for folders.

Comment: Hi @sidneydobber, thanks for the response. I am using git to deploy, but I've even tried to 777 the entire directory with no luck.

Comment: Scary bug I always hate these environment differences.